# Why even new SIM card is corrupting in my both phones old and new?

Tags: sim-card, sim-toolkit

My old phone which is running on `Android 4.0.4 Sony Xperia ST21i` (3G) and new one is `Android 9.0 ASUS Zenfone Max Pro M2`(4G) but this is not a case.

> I've same problem in my new phone that I was facing in my old phone.

Problem is that I was unable to use `Internet` and sometimes `calls couldn't connect too`.

My assumption :

> Because my old phone's SIM slot pins was scratching card and make it have such behavior.

So It is same in my new phone too, even I had changed SIM card few times but problem was same.

Now also I've changed a SIM card expecting positive result but it doesn't.

In both phones no SIM toolkit is present when insert SIM card.

But when I use other's SIM card it was there.

I was using Vodafone 3G in my old phone but when I bought new phone I used same SIM in it but later I have ported it with Jio 4G.

I've checked with both providers other SIM cards from another person their SIM cards working fine and SIM toolkit also present.

Restored APN settings even suggested by customer care.

> I found that even new SIM card is corrupting when I'm insert in phone no matter in old or new.

**"I think my new phone infected as I've used old SIM card from old phone."**

So how can I get rid of this?

Comment: Which cellular service provider's SIM card are you using? To which service provider this another person's SIM card belongs? Have you contacted customer care and complained about this issue? Have you verified that the internet settings are saved inside the phone? Which Android phone are you using? Do you not get internet connectivity and call functionality on any of 2g/3g/4g?

Comment: I seconded Firelord's comment and probably going further: have you visited a physical Jio customer care to let them test and confirm if your new SIM card is broken?

Comment: I visited store but they said I've already changed SIM card so they won't give me new one.